# Normalisation of Complex Morlet Wavelet

Tags: wavelet, transform, integration

I am currently writing an essay on Wavelet transforms, and as part of such, I am trying to show that the Morlet wavelet satisfies the standard criteria:

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \psi(t) dt = 0
$$
$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} |\psi(t)|^2 dt = 1
$$

Using the following definition from [this article](http://quanta.ws/ojs/index.php/quanta/article/view/5) (as cited on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet)):

$$
\psi_{\sigma }(t)=c_{\sigma }e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}t^{2}}\left(e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)
$$
With $\sigma$ our "reference frequency" parameter and $c_\sigma$ is our normalisation constant:
$$
c_{\sigma }=\pi^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(1+e^{-\sigma ^{2}}-2e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)^{-{\frac {1}{2}}}
$$

However, when computing the integral for the "unit energy" condition, I obtain:

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} |\psi_\sigma(t)|^2 dt
= \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left|c_{\sigma }e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}t^{2}}(e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}})\right|^2 dt
= c_{\sigma}^2\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}}\left(e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)^2 dt
= c_\sigma^2 \left[2\sqrt{{\pi}}\left(e^{-{\sigma}^2}-e^{-\frac{3}{4}\sigma^2}\right)\right]
= \frac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\left(2e^{-{\sigma}^2}-2e^{-\frac{3}{4}\sigma^2}\right)}
{\sqrt{\pi}\left(1+e^{-\sigma ^{2}}-2e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)}
\neq 1
$$

For this to be one, our normalisation constant would have to be:

$$
c_\sigma = \pi^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(2e^{-\sigma ^{2}}-2e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)^{-{\frac {1}{2}}}
$$

I am inclined to believe the source is correct based on plotting this function - simultaneously I cannot find the error in my integration:

#### My Solution:

\begin{align*}
            \int^\infty_{-\infty} |\psi_\sigma(t)|^2 dt
            &= \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left|c_{\sigma }e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}t^{2}}(e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}})\right|^2 dt
            = c_{\sigma}^2\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}}\left(e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)^2 dt\\
            &= c_{\sigma }^2\left(\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-2i\sigma t-t^{2}}dt 
            -2e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-i\sigma t-t^{2}} dt
            + e^{-\sigma ^{2}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}} dt\right)
        \end{align*}
Consider each of these integrals separately:
\begin{align}
        \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-2i\sigma t-t^{2}} dt
        &= \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-(t+i\sigma)^2-\sigma^2} dt
        = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\sigma^2}}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(t+i\sigma)^2} dt&\\
        &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\sigma^2}}{2} \:\left[erf(t+i\sigma)\right]^\infty_{-\infty}
        = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-\sigma^2}?\nonumber&
    \end{align}
\begin{align}
        \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-i\sigma t-t^{2}} dt
        &= \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-\left(t+\frac{i\sigma}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}} dt
        = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}}}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\left(t+\frac{i\sigma}{2}\right)^2} dt&\\
        &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}}}{2} \:\left[erf\!\left(t+\frac{i\sigma}{2}\right)\right]^\infty_{-\infty}
        = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}}?\nonumber&
    \end{align}
\begin{align}
        &\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}} dt
        = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{2e^{-t^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}dt
        = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \:[erf(t)]^\infty_{-\infty}
        = \sqrt{\pi}&
    \end{align}
Substituting these back into our equation:
\begin{align*}
        \int^\infty_{-\infty} |\psi_\sigma(t)|^2 dt
        &= c_{\sigma }^2\left(\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\sigma^2} 
        -2e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}}\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}}
        + e^{-\sigma ^{2}}\sqrt{\pi}\right)\\
        &= 2\sqrt{\pi}c_{\sigma }^2\left(e^{-\sigma^2} -e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)\\
        &= \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}\left(e^{-\sigma^2} -e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)}
            {\left(\pi^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(1+e^{-\sigma ^{2}}-2e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)^{{\frac {1}{2}}}\right)^2}\\
        &= \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}\left(e^{-\sigma^2} -e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)}
            {\sqrt{\pi}\left(1+e^{-\sigma ^{2}}-2e^{-{\frac {3}{4}}\sigma ^{2}}\right)}
    \end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't correctly compute the squared magnitude of a complex-valued function. You just took the square instead of the squared magnitude:

\begin{align*}
|\psi_{\sigma}(t)|^2 &= c_{\sigma }^2e^{-t^{2}}\left|e^{-i\sigma t}-e^{-\sigma ^{2}/2}\right|^2 \\
&= c_{\sigma }^2e^{-t^{2}}\left(1-2e^{-\sigma^2/2}\cos(\sigma t)+e^{-\sigma^2}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_{\sigma}(t)|^2 dt &= c_{\sigma }^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}}\left(1-2e^{-\sigma^2/2}\cos(\sigma t)+e^{-\sigma^2}\right)dt \\
&=c_{\sigma }^2\left(1+e^{-\sigma^2}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt-2c_{\sigma }^2e^{-\sigma^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\cos(\sigma t)dt\\
&= c_{\sigma }^2\left(1+e^{-\sigma^2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}-2c_{\sigma }^2e^{-\sigma^2/2}e^{-\sigma^2/4}\sqrt{\pi}\\&=c_{\sigma}^2\sqrt{\pi}\left(1+e^{-\sigma^2}-2e^{-3\sigma^2/4}\right)
\end{align*}

which results in the correct value of $c_{\sigma}$. Note that the integrals above are standard integrals which can be found in integration tables or which can be solved with a little help from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much :)